# Bootstrap 4 sticky-top for nav stopped working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, navbar

My navigation bar is supposed to stick to the top when scrolling. This worked for a while until I attempted to move the login button to the right. After many unsuccessful attempts at moving the login button, I revert back to what I had prior and the sticky nav bar stopped working.

Here is the code for the nav bar https://codeshare.io/GLJmWV

From my googling, I have tried some CSS classes to fix it. Everything I found has either not worked or just fixed the nav bar to the top of the screen but that won't work since I have a title above the nav bar to start.

I have attempted:

- position: sticky
- a class with position: fixed, width: 100%, top: 0
- reverting to an old file that was working as intended
- justify-right
- text-right
- and a few various other things I cannot remember at the moment

Edit:
Here is the code for the entire page https://codeshare.io/a30RoL
and here the css code I wrote as well https://codeshare.io/2W87m8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works for me, but it's better to use fixed not sticky. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19501919/difference-between-positionsticky-and-positionfixed)

This means the problem is somewhere else, have you tried to copy the bootstrap one:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Fixed navbar</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
          <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Also there are some issues with Chrome, if you use overflow: hidden, it won't work.

Comment: That code does work however it fixes it to the top of the screen permanently. I would like to have it so that the nav bar does not start at the top though. here is the html for the whole page https://codeshare.io/a30RoL and here is the mainstyle.css https://codeshare.io/2W87m8.

Comment: Ah, it has something to do with Chrome, in firefox it works well. Let me have a look if I can find a fix.

Comment: Found it, if you use overflow: hidden, in chrome 'sticky' wont work. You use overflow-x: hidden; in your html, body. Remove this and your sticky header will work again.